# Directories are listed when running Asp.Net application in IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created an Asp.Net application. It is running successfully in Asp.Net server. My requirement is to run that application in IIS server. I have created a deployment package in Visualstudio. And added that directory to IIS Application pool. Everything is fine.

When i right click on that application and Browse that application i expected to run an asp.net web page. But it appeared as a Directory Listing shown as below.

```
 localhost - /SendTile_deploy/


 [To Parent Directory]


1/11/2013  4:37 PM         3988 SendTile.deploy-readme.txt

1/11/2013  4:37 PM        12891 SendTile.deploy.cmd

1/11/2013  4:37 PM          163 SendTile.SetParameters.xml

1/11/2013  4:37 PM          563 SendTile.SourceManifest.xml

 1/11/2013  4:37 PM        11506 SendTile.zip
```

Is my deployment is correct..?
or i missed any process..?
I am a new bee to Asp.Net.
Any one please help me. If this application works i have to add a dataBase and run that application in IIS.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What's in SendTile.zip? IIS expects default files to load like index.html, default.aspx, if that file list is anything to go by you have none of those. Where is your actual ASP.NET application code?

Comment: SendTile.zip is the zip file created in deployment. It contains content folder, archive.xml,parameters.xml,systeminfo.xml.  In the content folder web.config, SendTile.aspx, bin folder are there.

Comment: I assume deploy.cmd actually does the deployment. Nuke all the files and put the contents of SendTile.zip in the directory instead, as that's your actual website.

Comment: Now i have only added sendTile.deploy only.. Then i got the same listing with only sendTile.deploy file

Comment: NOT the deploy file. The files in the SendTile.zip, the content folder (It should have things like a bin folder, web.config etc).

Comment: Yaa. I have moved that zip file into another folder and added that folder to iis. when i browse that the same sendTile.zip listing is opened. I have also tried by extracting and adding those files in .zip folder. In that case also i saw the same listing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22586/discussion-between-user1608857-and-lloyd)

Answer (score -1):

You'll either need to create a default document (via IIS manager) or disable directory browsing by pasting the following in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the issue was clearly caused by misunderstanding of the web deployment package, not what you described.